# Как настроить krakend, чтобы возвращать массивы из модифицированных lua данных?

Tags: lua, микросервисы

Есть массив, которые необходимо вернуть как массив данных, в ответе от бэка всё приходит корректно, на стороне гейта отдает в виде таблиц lua или строкой(если использовать json.lua), можно ли каким-то образом конфигурировать, чтобы возвращать массивы?